# OpenAL error capturing audio

Tags: c++, openal

I'm using the OpenAL framework (https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft) to capture audio from microphone. The main file is (found here on stackoverflow) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "AL/al.h"
#include "AL/alc.h"
using namespace std;

const int SRATE = 44100;
const int SSIZE = 1102;

ALbyte buffer[220500];
ALint sample;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    alGetError();
    ALCdevice *device = alcCaptureOpenDevice(NULL, SRATE, AL_FORMAT_STEREO16, SSIZE);
    if (alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR) {
        return 0;
    }
    alcCaptureStart(device);

    while (true) {
        alcGetIntegerv(device, ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, (ALCsizei)sizeof(ALint), &sample);
        alcCaptureSamples(device, (ALCvoid *)buffer, sample);

        // ... do something with the buffer 
    }

    alcCaptureStop(device);
    alcCaptureCloseDevice(device);
    return 0;
}
```

to compile the main file I use the following CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project( SharedLibrary C CXX )

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -fPIC -fpermissive")

set(OPENAL_ROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openal/")

set(OPENAL_LIB_DIR "${OPENAL_ROOT}build")
set(OPENAL_INCLUDE_DIR "${OPENAL_ROOT}include/AL")

include_directories(${OPENAL_INCLUDE_DIR})

link_directories(${OPENAL_LIB_DIR})

add_executable( main main.cpp )

target_link_libraries( main openal)
```

The compiling works fine but when I run the ./main I obtain this:

```
AL lib: (WW) alGetError: Querying error state on null context (implicitly 0xa004)
AL lib: (WW) jack_msg_handler: Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
AL lib: (WW) jack_msg_handler: Cannot connect to server request channel
AL lib: (WW) jack_msg_handler: jack server is not running or cannot be started
AL lib: (WW) jack_msg_handler: JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
AL lib: (WW) jack_msg_handler: JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
AL lib: (WW) ALCjackBackendFactory_init: jack_client_open() failed, 0x11
AL lib: (WW) alc_initconfig: Failed to initialize backend "jack"
AL lib: (WW) alGetError: Querying error state on null context (implicitly 0xa004)
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first warning is trivial to solve: don't call `alGetError` if no OpenAL function have been called before.

Then please have a look at section 6.4.2 in https://openal.org/documentation/openal-1.1-specification.pdf .

You can read that `alcCaptureOpenDevice` returns NULL when failing. You should check for the return value.

Also, here you give NULL as first argument of `alcCaptureOpenDevice` falling back to a default device you probably don't have. It is recommended to query the list of the available devices and then opening one of them (This is also described in the pdf).

Comment: Hi Tezirg, thanks for your answer. I read section 6.4.2 and I tried to print the ALC_CAPTURE_DEVICE_SPECIFIER. It returns 'Alsa Default' but I still get errors

Comment: So you still have errors when feeding 'Alsa Default' to the function ? Do you get any other values from this listing ?
Did you checked the return value ?

Comment: yes, I still get errors even if I use 'ALSA Default'. In particular, all the errors are releated to jack server....that is strange because I'm using ALSa, no?

Comment: Do you get any other values from this listing ? Did you checked the return value ?